# Standard sheet sizes for bleeds

Tags: print-design, bleed, paper-size

Are there standard sheet sizes for bleeds? My small printer can print slightly larger than A4, which would allow me to print things with bleeds and trim them—if only I could find paper that were A4 plus 3 mm around the edges. But I can't find anything like it. What do print shops use when they need to print with bleed? I seem to recall a "Super A3" that was A3 plus some extra space suitable for bleeds, but now I can't even find that.

Comment: See [International raw sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#International_raw_sizes) - the SRA series is typically used in offset lithography when bleeds are required. But these are for commercial printing presses, not home printing machines. Check your user manual to find the maximum sheet size possible.

Comment: I print on larger paper and cut down. For example, if I wanted 8.5x11 with bleed, I would print 2-up on 12x18 paper and cut down.